# How to use Nokogiri show nodes with a specific td class

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm having problems showing all the class from a specific `<td>` tag and class.

It should show all four items from the link but instead it's only showing the first item.

The IP should be within the US to show the items from Google Shopping:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/shopping/product/13109814219830976487/plusbox/8460070?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD7rnmjpTaAhVR4WMKHW1DB04QhxoIOQ'))
puts html.css('td.d4Zjj').text
# => Microsoft Project 2010 Standard AE 1 PC
```

I expect to see:

```
Microsoft Project 2010 Standard AE 1 PC 

Microsoft Project 2010 Standard License 2 Installs  

Microsoft Project 2010 Standard Retail Box  

Microsoft Project 2010 Standard License (3 License)
```

Comment: Your example lists four different text elements corresponding to the "td" elements with class "d4Zjj". What do you expect should be happening instead?

Comment: I'm expecting it should show all elements with "d4Zjj".

Comment: I only see four elements with that class in the document at that URL, it seems like the code is behaving correctly to me.

Comment: So it seems Sir. It's working on other links but with this one it's not.

Comment: Those classes are dynamic. Don't expect them to stay long.

Comment: I agree @pguardiario. But my main concern is getting each item for my list.

Comment: This is an old question. Google uses a LOT of DHTML now, so don't scrape pages, use their API instead.

Comment: When asking, you need to show the minimal HTML you're searching in the question itself, along with the expected output that HTML will result in. Using a link will return different information because the pages change. See "[ask]" and all its linked pages, along with "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"

Answer (score 0):

If your selector is right, you should get an array when your code looks like:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.google.com/shopping/product/13109814219830976487/plusbox/8460070?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjD7rnmjpTaAhVR4WMKHW1DB04QhxoIOQ'))
html.css('td.d4Zjj').each do |em|
  puts em.text
end
```

Comment: Same thing happens, it only shows the first item Sir.

Comment: Using `css` always returns a NodeSet, even if it's a single item that matched the selector. A NodeSet is akin to an Array.